# How to interpret ``underfull'' warnings in alignment?

Tags: tex-core, alignment

I'm trying to figure out why there are warnings for 125pt case of AT&T table example in *TeXbook*. While trying to understand the meaning of these warnings, I came across p.302 of *TeXbook*, that says:

> For example,
>   suppose you say ‘`\tabskip=0pt plus10pt \halign to200pt{&#\hfil\cr...\cr}`’, and
>   suppose that the aligned material turns out to make two columns of widths 50 pt and
>   60 pt, respectively. Then you get the following message:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 2698) in alignment at lines 11--18
[] []
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x200.0, glue set 3.0
.\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 10.0
.\unsetbox(0.0+0.0)x50.0
.\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 10.0
.\unsetbox(0.0+0.0)x60.0
.\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 10.0
```

Let's construct a complete example:

```
\tabskip=0pt plus10pt \halign to200pt{&#\hfil\cr
  \hbox to50pt{}&\hbox to60pt{}\cr}
\end
```

The log from this example does not match the *TeXbook*: the last line is

```
.\glue 0.0 plus 10.0
```

Can anybody construct an example that log will match *TeXbook*? This would help to understand how to interpret warning messages for alignments.

Comment: Seems like it's a bug in TeX The Program, because the last glue *is* `\tabskip` glue, and thus should be marked as such.

Comment: I can't see why the final tabskip is not marked as such, worth raising with Karl Berry (acting as Knuth's filter for bug reports these days)

Comment: If you mean the `Overfull \hbox (4.37805pt too wide) in alignment` warning in the AT&T example note the examples are set using  `\font\ninerm=cmr9 \ninerm`  not in cmr10

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect this is a bug.

If I modify your test slightly to

```
\showboxdepth3
\showboxbreadth100
\tracingoutput1
\tracingonline1

\tabskip=0pt plus10pt \halign to200pt{&#\hfil\cr
  \hbox to50pt{}&\hbox to60pt{}\cr}

\bye
```

Then the final tabskip is not marked as such in the underfull message:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 2698) in alignment at lines 7--8
 [] [] 

\hbox(0.0+0.0)x200.0, glue set 3.0
.\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 10.0
.\unsetbox(0.0+0.0)x50.0
.\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 10.0
.\unsetbox(0.0+0.0)x60.0
.\glue 0.0 plus 10.0
```

But it is marked as such in the final set box in the shipped out page:

```
.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x200.0, glue set 633.20255fill
..\glue(\topskip) 10.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x200.0, glue set 3.0
...\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 10.0
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x50.0 []
...\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 10.0
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x60.0 []
...\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 10.0
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill
```

You can get the output shown for the unset alignment by adding a final unused column to the `\halign` preamble:

```
\showboxdepth3
\showboxbreadth100
\tracingoutput1
\tracingonline1

\tabskip=0pt plus10pt \halign to200pt{&#\hfil&#\cr
  \hbox to50pt{}&\hbox to60pt{}\cr}

\bye
```

produces the documented underfull warning:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 2698) in alignment at lines 7--8
 [] [] 

\hbox(0.0+0.0)x200.0, glue set 3.0
.\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 10.0
.\unsetbox(0.0+0.0)x50.0
.\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 10.0
.\unsetbox(0.0+0.0)x60.0
.\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 10.0
```

Comment: I see it, but I can hardly believe it: so, the listing on page 302 of _The TeXbook_ would be an artifact, and not the result of an actual TeX run?  Should we think that Knuth invented details like the input line numbers where the alignment occurs?  Or perhaps, this bug was introduced in some version of TeX released after _The TeXbook_ had been written?

Comment: So, the fix must be done somewhere in the code that implements "a handy feature that helps a lot in cases like this" (p.241 of TeXbook)? Because if we do not use the starting `&`, all is OK. (like in your example (where repetition is not done) and in explicit `#\hfil&#\hfil\cr`)

Comment: @IgorLiferenko somewhere in the section of tex.web that starts `@* \[37] Alignment. It's sort of a miracle whenever \.{\\halign} and \.{\\valign} work, because they cut across so many of the control structures of \TeX.` :-) I did have a look to see if I could trace this code but got a bit lost and decided to simply recommend you push it to DEK for consideration, which I gather you have done.

Comment: I fixed it. `@x
link(p):=new_glue(glue_ptr(cur_loop));
@y
link(p):=new_glue(glue_ptr(cur_loop));
subtype(link(p)):=tab_skip_code+1
@z`

Comment: @IgorLiferenko excellent! Did you report that back?

Comment: Yes. I reported that.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko hopefully then you will eventually get listed in DEK's hall of fame of people who found bugs:-)

Comment: Yes, I'm lucky :-) But this was also a terrific occasion to get acquainted with \halign code and with Volume B in general.